# Open source 3D asset management (PHP/MySQL/HTML5)

Tags: php, mysql, 3d

I am looking for an asset management system which:

- I could run on our PHP/MySQL server.
- Could store files in a tree directory structure.
- Could either preview 3D file formats or would allow to add a custom thumbnail to a file.

It would be great if the system:

- Would allow to add multiple asset versions.
- Would support multiple users.

Thank you very much for any recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

There are some free (limited) software for create 3d asset model and web interaction platform: **blender**, **unity**.

[Cesium](https://cesiumjs.org/) is a platform for 3d asset presentation. GLTF format models can be incorporated to the platform.